# find and replace variable using cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

i want to replace a specific string in a file with another variable string.
i have 100 file with name attack_1 to attack_100 that contain just a number.
and also i have one file name is 1.dat
i have a string "angle=5" in 1.dat file that i want to replace it with not specific string but with "angle=variable" that variable is that number in each attack.txt files.
i write two kind of batch but both of them can't do it.

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do (
echo %%x
set /p a=<C:\Users\amirhosssein\Desktop\airfoil\batch\JOU\attack_%%x.txt
%a%
powershell -Command "(gc 1.dat) -replace 'airfoilmesh', 'airfoilmesh_%%x' -
replace 'angle=5','angle=%a%' | Out-File Okjou%%x.jou"
)
```

and also this

```
cd "C:\Users\amirhosssein\Desktop\airfoil\batch\JOU"
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do (
echo %%x
powershell -command "$amir=Get-Content attack_%%x.txt"
powershell -command "Write-Output amir"
powershell -Command "(gc 1.dat) -replace 'airfoilmesh', 'airfoilmesh_%%x' -
replace 'angle=5','angle=%amir%' | Out-File Okjou%%x.jou"
)
```

non of them working well. they replace but the angle=5 replace with angle= .(empty)

Comment: I strongly recommend that you convert the entire process to PowerShell.

Comment: Is it possible that the variable could be (at some time), 55 (e.g. - angle=55) or in other words, have more than one 5 in its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested earlier, doing it all in PowerShell would be a good idea.

```
Set-Location 'C:\Users\amirhosssein\Desktop\airfoil\batch\JOU'
$f = Get-Content 1.dat

1..100 |
    $amir = Get-Content -Path attack_$_.txt
    $f -replace 'airfoilmesh', "airfoilmesh_$amir" -replace 'angle=5', "angle=$amir" |
        Out-File -FilePath "Okjou$amir.jou" -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Please check this again. I changed it to only read `1.dat` once rather than 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do (
 echo %%x
 for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("C:\Users\amirhosssein\Desktop\airfoil\batch\JOU\attack_%%x.txt") do (
  powershell -Command "(gc 1.dat) -replace 'airfoilmesh', 'airfoilmesh_%%x' -
  replace 'angle=5','angle=%%a' | Out-File Okjou%%x.jou"
 )
)
```

Using your hybrid approach.

Note that your code is failing because of the `delayed expansion` trap (many articles on this on SO) so `%a%` would be replaced by *nothing* as `a` is not set at the start of the `for` loop.

In this replacement, `%%a` is assigned the value from the `attack` file, so `%%a`, not `%a%` needs to be used as `angle`. The `usebackq` is only required if the *attack* filename is "quoted", and quoting is only required if the filepath contains spaces, so

```
 for /f %%a in (C:\Users\amirhosssein\Desktop\airfoil\batch\JOU\attack_%%x.txt) do (
```

would also work if the filepath does *not* contain spaces.